# Windows Server Time not syncing correctly (at all?)

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019, time-synchronization

I have a domain controller running Server 2019. I have two other DCs in the domain. On the server that is running the PDC Emulator roll, I configured it to point to the Navy's time servers.

`w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:"tick.usno.navy.mil tock.usno.navy.mil ntp2.usno.navy.mil" /syncfromflags:manual /reliable:yes /update`

This completes successfully. I restart the time service:

`net stop w32time && net start w32time`

After a while, I noticed the time on my systems in the whole domain was wrong. I'm not always in this domain, so by the time that I noticed, it was 5 minutes behind actual time. Now it is 6.5 minutes behind.

If I restart the time service again and then query the peers, all three state are active:

```
C:\windows\system32>w32tm /query /peers /verbose
#Peers: 3

Peer: ntp2.usno.navy.mil
State: Active
Time Remaining: 54.2426825s
Mode: 1 (Symmetric Active)
Stratum: 0 (unspecified)
PeerPoll Interval: 0 (unspecified)
HostPoll Interval: 6 (64s)
Last Successful Sync Time: (null)
LastSyncError: 0x800705B4 (This operation returned because the timeout period expired. )
LastSyncErrorMsgId: 0x00000000 (Succeeded)
AuthTypeMsgId: 0x0000005A (NoAuth )
Resolve Attempts: 0
ValidDataCounter: 1
Reachability: 2

Peer: tock.usno.navy.mil
State: Active
Time Remaining: 54.2582623s
Mode: 1 (Symmetric Active)
Stratum: 0 (unspecified)
PeerPoll Interval: 0 (unspecified)
HostPoll Interval: 6 (64s)
Last Successful Sync Time: (null)
LastSyncError: 0x800705B4 (This operation returned because the timeout period expired. )
LastSyncErrorMsgId: 0x00000000 (Succeeded)
AuthTypeMsgId: 0x0000005A (NoAuth )
Resolve Attempts: 0
ValidDataCounter: 1
Reachability: 2

Peer: tick.usno.navy.mil
State: Active
Time Remaining: 54.2729373s
Mode: 1 (Symmetric Active)
Stratum: 0 (unspecified)
PeerPoll Interval: 0 (unspecified)
HostPoll Interval: 6 (64s)
Last Successful Sync Time: (null)
LastSyncError: 0x800705B4 (This operation returned because the timeout period expired. )
LastSyncErrorMsgId: 0x00000000 (Succeeded)
AuthTypeMsgId: 0x0000005A (NoAuth )
Resolve Attempts: 0
ValidDataCounter: 1
Reachability: 2

C:\windows\system32>
```

If I then run a resync, it says it did not resync because no time data was available.

If I run a strip chart against tick, I get an error.

```
C:\windows\system32>w32tm /stripchart /computer:tick.usno.navy.mil
Tracking tick.usno.navy.mil [192.5.41.40:123].
The current time is 6/9/2022 11:51:23 AM.
11:51:23, error: 0x800705B4
11:51:26, error: 0x800705B4
11:51:29, error: 0x800705B4
^C
C:\windows\system32>
```

If I run a strip chart against a network switch that is running an ntp service and it gets time from an authenticated time source, I am way off time:

```
C:\windows\system32>w32tm /stripchart /computer:*.*.*.1
Tracking *.*.*.1 [*.*.*.1:123].
The current time is 6/9/2022 11:54:00 AM.
11:54:00, d:+00.0016961s o:+396.5884202s  [                           |                          @]
11:54:02, d:+00.0015396s o:+396.5886677s  [                           |                          @]
11:54:04, d:+00.0017477s o:+396.5889037s  [                           |                          @]
^C
C:\windows\system32>
```

Also, after about 4 or 5 minutes, my peers change to the pending state:

```
C:\windows\system32>w32tm /query /peers /verbose
#Peers: 3

Peer: ntp2.usno.navy.mil
State: Pending
Time Remaining: 848.7510630s
Mode: 0 (reserved)
Stratum: 0 (unspecified)
PeerPoll Interval: 0 (unspecified)
HostPoll Interval: 0 (unspecified)
Last Successful Sync Time: (null)
LastSyncError: 0x00000000 (Succeeded)
LastSyncErrorMsgId: 0x00000000 (Succeeded)
AuthTypeMsgId: 0x0000005A (NoAuth )
Resolve Attempts: 1
ValidDataCounter: 0
Reachability: 0

Peer: tick.usno.navy.mil
State: Pending
Time Remaining: 848.7514333s
Mode: 0 (reserved)
Stratum: 0 (unspecified)
PeerPoll Interval: 0 (unspecified)
HostPoll Interval: 0 (unspecified)
Last Successful Sync Time: (null)
LastSyncError: 0x00000000 (Succeeded)
LastSyncErrorMsgId: 0x00000000 (Succeeded)
AuthTypeMsgId: 0x0000005A (NoAuth )
Resolve Attempts: 1
ValidDataCounter: 0
Reachability: 0

Peer: tock.usno.navy.mil
State: Pending
Time Remaining: 848.7518290s
Mode: 0 (reserved)
Stratum: 0 (unspecified)
PeerPoll Interval: 0 (unspecified)
HostPoll Interval: 0 (unspecified)
Last Successful Sync Time: (null)
LastSyncError: 0x00000000 (Succeeded)
LastSyncErrorMsgId: 0x00000000 (Succeeded)
AuthTypeMsgId: 0x0000005A (NoAuth )
Resolve Attempts: 1
ValidDataCounter: 0
Reachability: 0

C:\windows\system32>
```

Changing my peer list to the network switch, I still have all these same problems. This system is a VM. For a while, I had it configured to sync its time with the host, but I have removed that setting a couple hours ago and it has only seemed to get farther from correct time. I have also rebooted the DC, no change.

I have no idea what else to try to get this to have correct time. I'll also include results from me querying the status. I also don't see any errors in the Windows Time Service log and nothing jumps out at me when I set the w32tm debug log.

```
C:\windows\system32>w32tm /query /status
Leap Indicator: 0(no warning)
Stratum: 1 (primary reference - syncd by radio clock)
Precision: -23 (119.209ns per tick)
Root Delay: 0.0000000s
Root Dispersion: 10.0000000s
ReferenceId: 0x4C4F434C (source name:  "LOCL")
Last Successful Sync Time: 6/9/2022 11:50:45 AM
Source: Local CMOS Clock
Poll Interval: 6 (64s)
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Make sure UDP port 123 (yes) is open in Windows and any external firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe my problem was two fold. First, the instructions I originally followed was if I was a Forest root DC. But since then, we started over and I'm a child domain, so I should have pointed to the forest root DC as my source. Once I changed to the correct source, things straightened out for me. The other problem was, I think my network team blocked the NTP traffic to the Navy servers some time between when I configured it and when I noticed the problem. That is why my DC kept showing the local CMOS as the source. But when I tried Stacker's suggestion, the source changed to the forest root DC even though I hadn't configured it. This link below is the article that suggested that the local CMOS source could be caused by a firewall block.
https://www.renanrodrigues.com/post/how-to-configure-ntp-server-in-active-directory-step-by-step

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your source is not set to be the local CMOS not the Navy

w32tm.exe /config /syncfromflags:manual /manualpeerlist:131.107.13.100,0x8 /reliable:yes /update

w32tm.exe /config /update

Open Group Policy Management Console
Create a new GPO
Open the GPO and navigate to Computer Settings -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Windows Time Service -> Time Providers
Double click the Configure Windows NTP Client.
Set the state to Enabled
Configure the Typeto NTP
Configure NTPServerto point to an IP address of a time server, followed by ,0x8, for example:  131.107.13.100,0x8
Close the Group Policy Editor
In the Security Filteringpane of the Group Policy management console remove Authenticated users for the newly created policy and add the machine that holds the PDC Emulatorrole
Link the GPO to Domain ControllersOU

Comment: Thank you for your response. Although your response did not fix my problem, it led me down a different troubleshooting path that ultimately did fix my problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).